# jquery hide() not working after page loads

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filtering

I think I'm missing something simple and obvious here - I'm working on a site where I need to filter portfolio categories, and also show the category description on the link click, but not for the "All" list item.

The page loads fine and then I can click and filter the categories/descriptions fine, but then if you click back to "All" the category description for whatever was last clicked remains even though it should hide.

Here is the dev site (Wordpress) - http://foothilltile.com/dev/products/

Here is the relevant code:

```
<ul class="filter-nav">
  <li>
    <h4><?php _e("Filter:", "elemis"); ?></h4>
  </li>
  <li class="selected-1 all"><a href="#" data-value="all">
    <h4><?php _e("All", "elemis"); ?></h4>
    </a></li>
    <?php 
      $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=kind&orderby=id'); 
      foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $input = '<li><a href="#" data-value="'.$cat->category_nicename.'" class="'.$cat->category_nicename.'"><h4>';
        $input .= $cat->cat_name;
        $input .= '</h4></a></li>';
        echo $input;
      }
     ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- End Portfolio Navigation --> 

<div id="category-descriptions">

    <ul class="descriptions-list">
      <li class="all"></li>
      <?php 
          $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=kind&orderby=id'); 
          foreach ($categories as $cat) {
          $input = '<li class="cat-desc '.$cat->category_nicename.'">';
          $input .= $cat->description;
          $input .= '</li>';
          echo $input;
          }
      ?>

    </ul>
</div> <!--/category-descriptions -->`
```

And then the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.filter-nav li a').click(function() {
    // fetch the class of the clicked item
    var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');

    if (ourClass == 'all') {
      // this should hide the li's on load - but doesn't? 
      $('.descriptions-list').children('li.cat-desc').hide();
    }
    else {

      // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
      $('.descriptions-list').children('li:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide();
      // show all elements that do share ourClass
      $('.descriptions-list').children('li.' + ourClass).show();
  }
    return false;
  });
});
```

And the only relevant css is the li.cat-desc is set to display:none.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm always confusing the order of code in jQuery (noob, for sure) so thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor for "All" has no class "all"...thats the problem. The class is set to the 
li-element... 
Add the class to the a-element and it should be work

Comment: Thanks so much s4ty - that was exactly what I saw - my eyes just kept missing it.

Answer (score 0):

The click event is assigned to anchor tag `a` so `$(this).attr('class');` will refer to the anchor tag class attribute. so instead of this you should rather try this

`var ourClass =$(this).parent("li").attr('class');`

or may be only

`var ourClass =$(this).parent().attr('class');`

Comment: Hi Dharmesh - thank you for answering - this didn't actually fix my problem (because I do want to get the class of the anchors) but it helped me look at the code fresh and see that the issue was that the "All" list item didn't HAVE a class of "all". I've got it sorted now. Thanks again!